# macOS disk image - create in terminal with password

Tags: macos, shell, pipe, diskimage

macOS 12.1 here. In the man page for hdiutil there is this example for creating a disk image with a password.

```
Creating an encrypted single-partition image without user interaction:
       printf pp|hdiutil create -encryption -stdinpass -size 9m sp.dmg
```

This works. It creates a 9MB .dmg file with a password but I don't get to see what the password is. I know the "printf" is supposed to show something but I don't know what the "pp" that follows that does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command shown begins with `printf pp|`, that is the command *printf*, the two letters `pp`, and a pipe.  *printf* outputs its argument (the two letter p's).  The pipe has the effect of sending those two letter p's to the following command, which as you know asks for a password.  Therefor the password you have given to the `.dmg` is **pp**.

---

[image]

> ###### Fun fact.  The pipeline was invented in 1973 by Douglas McIlroy and later coded by Ken Thompson (Inventor of the B programming language).

Comment: Very cool. Thank you. I don't do command line enough to keep it sharp.

Answer (score -1):

OK, this was dumb. The example creates the .dmg file WITHOUT user interaction. The correct line is:

```
hdiutil create -encryption -stdinpass -size 9m sp.dmg
```

You'll get asked for the password. If only I read the description more carefully.

Comment: This should be part of the question.